# Error C3861: 'execute_assert': identifier not found

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

Alright, this should be easy enough. 
I am programming a dll whose source code is too big to post here. 
But it only has three errors from the same repeating code...

```
// Test parameter s
execute_assert(s >= MAX_ACL_DEPTH, "MAX_ACL_DEPTH too small");
```

Now I know EXECUTE_ASSERT is a macro so I think I only need to include a header.

I just need to know the header.

I'm building using Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried searching for it on e.g. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/s)? And you do know that both C and C++ is case-sensitive?

Comment: Have you noticed that the only documented one is `EXECUTE_ASSERT` and it is defined in DirectShow (*not* part of Windows SDK), whereas you need `execute_assert`? Those are unrelated things. Your app probably defined `execute_assert` somewhere internally. Do a global search inside your project.

Comment: I think one of the issues is that the code was generated in Xubuntu and I wanted to build a .lib file and so I imported everything to Windows including the headers.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the insight.
I included...

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Samples\multimedia\directshow\baseclasses

In project properties after adding

```
#include <Streams.h>
#include <wxdebug.h>
```

and changed

```
execute_assert
```

to

```
EXECUTE_ASSERT
```

Result...

```
1>  Generating Code...
1>c:\users\...\Analytical.lib
========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```